# Create php variables from a single input

Tags: php, html, variables, input

I have this input:

```
<input name="an_input" id="an_input">
```

An user write in the input field some words separated by comma.

Let's say he introduces milk, coffee, tea.

I want to create a php variable for each word:

```
$milk = "milk";
$coffe = "coffe";
$tea = "tea";
```

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: What have you tried?  The `explode()` function seems useful here.  Though an array seems a lot more practical than separate variables.  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: If the variables will have the same name as the values, how would you even know what variables exist? How would you use them? And what would you do if any value would overwrite any existing variable?

Comment: I've added an answer for you. is that helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Lets try

```
<?php
    $user_input = 'milk, coffee, tea';
    list($milk, $coffee, $tee) = array_map('trim',explode(',', $user_input));
    echo $milk,$coffee, $tee;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/aXtA0

**OR** If multiple comma separated value comes from input then you can do it using only the [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
 $user_input = 'milk, coffee, tea, biscuit, jam, jelly, nougut';
 $results =  array_map('trim',explode(',', $user_input));
 foreach($results as $result){
     ${$result} = $result;
 }
 echo $tea;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/mdUdQ

Comment: Isn't it getting input from a input field? If they added more then three items, that wouldn't work. Also, if I understand this question, the variables aren't the exact same as the input

Comment: @Lorddirt, Edited my answer and posted another way to observe multiple variable

Comment: This answer is great, exactly what I had in mind, but for all intents and purposes it's highly impractical.

Comment: @Andrew I totally agreed with you :) . Actually I prefer `list()` for small and known number of inputs.

Comment: I don't think there is any correct answer to this problem, mostly because the problem itself is the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah your're right :)

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @MikeyJY you're welcome, By the way you can mark it as an answer :)